# Mac keeps crashing and restarting when in try to run a code

Tags: python, pong

**New to python and trying to learn through freecodecamp by making easy games (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=139&v=XGf2GcyHPhc&feature=emb_title&t=142s), however, my windows keeps crashing when I try to run this code to create a Pong game. Used both Spyder, as well as VSC and the same thing, happened on both where it crashed and restarted my computer**

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.set](width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)


paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)
```

Comment: your code is not valid python syntax

Comment: Whats the difference between python and python syntax?

Comment: Syntax is the structure of your code. So when I say its not valid syntax I mean your code won't run at all. So maybe you have pasted it wrong here but for example. `wn.set](width=800, height=600)` will generate an error

Comment: I'm following a video by Christian Thompson and following what he used, however, it's working on his video but isn't working for me.

Comment: http://christianthompson.com/sites/default/files/Pong/pong.py

Comment: thats not the same as you pasted here. i can confirm running the code in the pong.py does work

Comment: for example in pong.py they have `wn.setup(width=800, height=600)` but in your code you have `wn.set](width=800, height=600)`